# Game is very slow. How to run it fast?

Tags: android, optimization

I'm developing Android 2D game by extending `SurfaceView`. 
This is my first game on Android, so I'm not very knowledgeable. I have taken care to optimise the code, but still it's running very slowly.

I'm trying to draw 5 objects, 2 circles, 2 lines and 1 text by using canvas. The circle's radius has to change second by second. I could not to see a change in the circle's radius; it might be software rendering problem. Circles radius is generated by a random value for every second. This random generation is good.

How can I optimise my game to run faster?

Comment: You say you've taken care to optimize it but you probably looked at the wrong things to optimize.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: hi thanks for comment, is there any tutorial to get start.

Comment: The main concern when learning to optimize is to learn to measure first. If you don't measure correctly, first you will optimize the wrong thing, second you won't actually learn to optimize, as you're only making random changes to the code without feedback. I have currently no idea how to measure performance on android (it's certainly possible and not too hard, only I've never done it), thus a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Not upvoted because the question as is is borderline off topic. Asking for tutorials about developing android games is far too broad and will get the question closed for being "how to get started", but it could be possible to salvage the question by focusing on how to detect performance issues on android in a specific development environment. But even then people other than me might still close vote it for being too broad.

Comment: I think this question is potentially salvagable with some more detail from the OP about the specific problem, and less focus on the "are there any tutorials" part.  Maybe describe what the game is like, how you're drawing objects, how many objects, at least give us something to start anyalzing things properly from.

Comment: I'm trying to draw 5 objects. 2 circles, 2 lines and 1 text by using canvas. circles radius has to change second by second. I could not able to see change in circles radius; it might be software rendering problem. Circles radius generation by random value for every second. This random generation is good.

Comment: @Moses - you should edit the question to include this information rather than provide it in a comment; that way the question will go into the reopen queue and the information will be permanently viewable (comments, by their nature, are temporary and subject to removal if things get too chatty).

Comment: It's already closed, but you could possibly get it opened again by adding the code you've written, and clearly marking what specific optimization you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make sure you are optimizing the right things you need to figure out which parts of the app are taking so long. Programs which measure programs like that are called "profilers". If you are using an IDE like Android Studio etc., there is usually a [profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-methodtrace.html) built in. The profiler should tell you which functions/methods are slow. Once you know which parts are slow, if you don't know how to make them fast you can ask another more specific question about the code in question.